# Not able to Delete an event Hub in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-eventhub, azure-eventgrid, hub

So I have created an event hub and linked a Kafka Service with it. I was able to successfully send the events to event hub, but I made an error while creating partitions in the event hub.

Not I want to Delete the event Hub and recreate it with the same name. But for some reason when I Delete it, Azure does not seems to remove it from main name space.

I can still see the event hub..

I even checked the activity logs and I can see that it is deleted, but for some reason I still see it.

PARTITION COUNT : 2
MESSAGE RETENTION: 7

Comment: You probably have to wait for some time for the changes to be reflected.

Comment: Hi peter, so I changed the message retention time to 1 day and waited 24+ hours to see if it is deleted. but the event hub is still there so not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Did you see any notification that the deletion was successful? What happens if you try it again ?

Comment: I do see the successful message.  And I see that in the Azure event log as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Auto topic creation is ON by default so Kafka producer keeps re-creating the eventhub when you delete it. You can either stop the Kafka producers or pick another eventhub name.

Comment: Hi Serkant, you are right on the point. I worked with the Microsoft support and they helped figure out the issue.